# How to map subdomains to multiple docker containers (as web servers) hosted using Elastic Bean Stack on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have seen an aws example of hosting a nginx server and a php server running on separate docker containers within an instance.

I want to use this infrastructure to host multiple docker containers (each being its own web server on a different unique port).

Each of these unique web application needs to be available on the internet with a unique subdomain.

Since one instance will not be enough for all the Docker containers, I will need them spread over multiple instances.

How can I host hundreds of docker containers over several instances, while one nginx-proxy container does the routing to map a subdomain to each web application container using it's unique port?

```
E.g. 

app1.mydomain.com --> docker container exposing port 10001
app2.mydomain.com --> docker container exposing port 10002
app3.mydomain.com --> docker container exposing port 10003
....
...
```

If I use a nginx-proxy container, it would be easy to map each port number to a different subdomain. This would be true of all the Docker containers are in the same instance as the nginx-proxy container.

But can I map it to docker containers that is hosted on a different instance. I am planning to use elastic beanstalk for creating new instances for the extra docker containers.

Now nginx is running on one instance, while there are containers on different instances.

How do I achieve the end goal of hundreds of web applications hosted on separate docker containers mapped to unique subdomains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, you question is not quite clear to me. It seems you could deploy an Nginx container in each instance having the proxy configuration for every app container you have on it, and as the cluster scales out, all them would have an Nginx as well. So, you could just set an ELB on top of it (Elastic Beanstalk supports it natively), and you would be good.

Nonetheless, I think you're intending to push Elastic Beanstalk to hard. I mean, it's not supposed to be used that way, like a big and generic Docker cluster. Elastic Beanstalk was built to facilitate application deployments, and nowadays containers are just one of the, let's say, platforms available (although it's not a language or framework, off course) for people to do it. But Elastic Beanstalk is not a container manager.

So, in my opinion, what makes sense is to deploy a single container per Beanstalk application with an ELB on top of it, so you don't need to worry about the underlying machines and their IPs. That way, you can easily set up a frontend proxy to route requests, because you have a permanent address for you application pool. And being independent pools, they can scale independently, and so on.

There are some more complex solutions out there which try to solve that problem of deploying containers in a wide single cluster, like [Google's Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/), and keeping track of them and providing endpoints for each application group. Also, there are solutions for dynamic reverse proxies like [this one](https://github.com/sourcelair/ceryx), recently released, and probably a lot of other solutions popping up every day, but all them would demand a lot of customization. But, in that case, we are not talking about an AWS solution.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer. You provided a valuable insight in that EBS solves the scaling problem for the same application. It cannot be used the way I am envisioning. I am still keeping this question open to see if there are some other solutions that can help.

Comment: Like I said, you can have an ELB on top of each application cluster/group/pool, so you have a single endpoint for each one, and don't need to worry about the underlying machines. So, your Nginx proxy could just proxy to those ELB addresses. Is it clear to you?

Comment: Not sure I got it. Can you break it down a little. Let's take an example. 10 EC2 instances with 5 applications each. Total 50 applications. What will be the subdomain mapping look like between the ELB and the Nginx proxy?

Comment: The concept is quite straightforward actually, although it's an advanced configuration for Elastic Beanstalk and you'll have to go through _.eb_ files, as the Console will not be enough for configuring everything you need. But, let's say, in each machine you have 5 apps, which ports range for 8001 to 8005. So, for each app you'll have a load balancer listening on the same port (8001-8005) and forwarding to app. So, then, you'll get an DNS record like app1.foo.bar, which itself is a proxy that balances to your app instances. So, you just use those addresses in you Nginx conf.

Comment: Take a look at [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html). It's exactly what you want to do, except for the frontend proxy (Nginx, in you case).

Comment: Ok. Got it. 1) Map Docker port to host port 2) Open that port in the elastic beanstack security group 3) Map that port in ELB 4) Map that port to a subdomain in the Nginx proxy that sits on top of all of this. Thank you!